# Android conhecimento de voz

Tags: android, android-studio, reconhecimento-de-voz

Estou fazendo uma app em que eu faço uma pergunta e o telemovel responde-me conforme a pergunta realizada,mas o problema é que o telemovel ouve mas não me responde, ou seja, não fala.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    private SpeechRecognizer mySpeechReconizer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Button mic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mic);
        mic.setOnClickListener((view) ->
        {

                Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
                mySpeechReconizer.startListening(i);


        });

        initializeTextToSpeech();
        initializeSpeechReconizer();
    }

    private void initializeSpeechReconizer() {
        if (SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this)) {
            mySpeechReconizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
            mySpeechReconizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEndOfSpeech() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                    List<String> res = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
                    processResult(res.get(0));

                }

                @Override
                public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processResult(String s) {
        s = s.toLowerCase();

        //Qual é o teu nome?

        if (s.indexOf("What") != -1){
            if (s.indexOf("your name") != -1){
                speak("two");
            }
            if (s.indexOf("time") != -1){
                Date now = new Date();
                String time = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this,now.getTime(),
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME);
                speak(time);
            }
        }

         else if (s.indexOf("open") != -1){
            if (s.indexOf("browser") != -1){
            }
                speak("Sou a Lian, fui fundada pelo Leandro e moro em Baião.");
        }
    }

    private void initializeTextToSpeech() {
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (myTTS.getEngines().size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Teste", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Locale l1 = new Locale("pt","PT");
                    myTTS.setLanguage(l1);
                    speak("Olá Leandro, estou pronta,podes falar!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void speak(String s) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=21){
            myTTS.speak(s,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
            } else{
            myTTS.speak(s,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myTTS.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ela fala em algum momento? Por exemplo quando inicia o textoToSpeech?

Comment: Sim fala o que eu inseri como mensagens de boas vindas